# Build Failed Error: Undefined Symbols

Tags: ios, delegates, uikit

I am getting this error when I try to build my project.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UINavigationBar.images", referenced from:
      -[UINavigationBar(CustomImage) drawRect:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[UINavigationBar(CustomImage) setImagesNames:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your AppDelegate class and check the include for your UINavigationBar category. 
Your category is either missing from the project, or it is private. My best guess is that it's missing or when you created it you didn't check the target checkbox. They removing it and re-add it. 
Be careful when you add it back to have your active target checked for the file.

Comment: How do you mean by removing it and re-adding it? Because the UINavigationBar is a part of the UIKit Framework. That framework is already added in the project.

Comment: UINavigationBar(CustomImage) - This is a category with additions over the UINavigationBar. You need to find where this is implemented, then remove/readd that file to your project.

Comment: But that is part of the UIKit framework. It is not a file that I have created on my own. I have tried to re-add the framework a couple of times already without any results.

Comment: UINavigationBar is part of UIKit. UINavigationBar(CustomImage) is a category of your own. Do a search in your project for UINavigationBar(CustomImage)

Comment: I found it. I tried to remove the file and add it to the project again, without any result. Is there something else I could try?

Comment: Check if the #include of the category file isn't missing

Comment: The category is build up in the AppDelegate. So there should be no import needed.